# Website on server is treating file paths differently than local version

Tags: javascript, html, css, server, localhost

using Localhost, my HTML/CSS/JQuery stack website works perfectly fine, however, when uploading to a server, things break. Specifically, the src paths from within the JavaScript files. After being uploaded, the index HTML can find the appropriate JS files through the script tags. However, from things go wrong from within those JS files that are linked...

Keeping things big picture, I have JS files that use paths to certain imgs, or other files. And those JS files are stored from within folders. So you have

```
.
├── index.html
|
├── js
│   └── components
│        └── functions.js
└── img
     └── circle.jpg
```

In index.html, functions.js is called. From within functions.js I have a path to a circle.jpg for example. On localhost the path is "../../img/circle.jpg" because it treats components folder as the current working directory (cwd) "you are in components folder working in the functions.js file, now go out and into img folder"

However, on the server, cwd is the root folder. I guess that is because function.js is called from index.html and because index.html is in the root so it says "to get to circle.jpg you have to go "img/circle.jpg"

**WHY?** This doesn't make sense, to have it work on the server I now have to change all my file paths from within the JS files. This apparently isn't an issue on the src paths in the HTML, because it recognizes the  tags and runs the Javascript. It breaks when trying to find the imgs based on the paths you give them. And it can't find the images in the JS based on those paths because of the above reasons. Instead of changing all the paths in the javascript how can I fix the imminent issue of the server treating the paths differently than the local version?

Comment: On `localhost` the path **should** be the same as the server; the path should be relative to `index.html`, and thus require a single `../`. I assume it works with two because `localhost` has no additional path to go 'up' to. Though if in doubt, why not just use absolute paths rather than relative ones? Like `/img/circle.jpg`.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the code? And why are you trying to read files using a relative path in JS?

Comment: how else would I read files?

Comment: @Jordan, there is something you are not telling us. Show us how you include that script in the html-file and how you refer to that image. There is no reason this should work differently on your local server vs your remote server, unless maybe you have some web server rewriting rules in play (on server or locally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a <**base href=""**> tag in the head section of index.html

```
<head>
<base href="/">
<!-- other head items -->
</head>
```

If your index.html is the root path of the domain (like **http:**//**someurl.com/index.html**), above should work. Or if the index.html is in a subfolder, provide the subfolder path as the **href** value. like,

```
<base href="/subfolder/">
```

Comment: index.html is in the root. By doing this will every single path in my js now start at the root (therefore if I go '../' then it technically goes outside the root)... is that what it will do? essentially standardize it?

Comment: I think it is better to use this way. can you post a working example of your problem?

Comment: but what is that solution DOING exactly, like i said in my last comment

Comment: <base> tag specifies the base URL for all relative URLs in a document. so every relative URLs in the your document starts from the base URL